# why scipy.sparse.linalg.LinearOperator has different behaviors with @, np.dot and np.matmul

Tags: arrays, numpy, scipy

I thought that when it comes to matrix-vector multiplication, the `@` operator and the functions `np.dot` and `np.matmul` were all 3 equivalent. They give the same result when the matrix is a `np.ndarray`:

```py
import numpy as np

M = np.ones((2, 2))
a = np.arange(2)
M @ a
Out[11]: array([1., 1.])
np.dot(M, a)
Out[12]: array([1., 1.])
np.matmul(M, a)
Out[13]: array([1., 1.])
```

However, they do not behave the same with scipy's LinearOperator interface

```py
from scipy.sparse.linalg import aslinearoperator

lM = aslinearoperator(M)
lM @ a
Out[15]: array([1., 1.])
np.dot(lM, a)
Out[16]: 
array([<2x2 _ScaledLinearOperator with dtype=float64>,
       <2x2 _ScaledLinearOperator with dtype=float64>], dtype=object)
np.matmul(lM, a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/luc/anaconda3/envs/ckm/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3437, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-17-287f28944706>", line 1, in <module>
    np.matmul(lM, a)
ValueError: matmul: Input operand 0 does not have enough dimensions (has 0, gufunc core with signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) requires 1)
```

I don't understand what is the difference between them functions.

Answer (score 1):

`lM` is not a `numpy` array, or subclass of that. `np.array(lM)` produces `()` shape object dtype array. That's why it doesn't work in `matmul`. `lM@a` and `lM.dot(a)` delegate the task to lM methods. The others make the erroneous conversion to `ndarray` first.

Comment: So that looks like an unintended behavior right? And do you know why `lM@a` and `np.dot(lM, a)` give different results? Thank you

Comment: `np.dot(lM,a)` is actually `np.dot(np.array(lM),a)`.  It's same problem as with `np.matmul`, only `matmul` does not work with 'scalar' arguments